# Kendo UI not loading data on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

**Please don't mark it as duplicate as there are other questions on SO with similar problem as well and I have gone though them.**

I am trying to load Kendo grid on button click but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I am attaching my files below:

**KendoData.cshtml**

```
    <div id="grid">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(<MvcApplication1.Models.Customer)
                .Name("AjaxGrid")
                .AutoBind(false) 
             .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
             .Ajax()
             .PageSize(20)
                  .Read(read => read.Action("KendoDataAjaxHandle", "Default1Controller"))
          )        
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    //Create a column bound to the ProductID property.
                    columns.Bound(customer => customer.CustomerAltID);
                    //Create a column bound to the ProductName property.
                    columns.Bound(customer => customer.CustomerName);
                    //Create a column bound to the UnitsInStock property.
                    columns.Bound(customer => customer.Gender);
                })
                .Pageable() //Enable the paging.
                .Sortable() //Enable the sorting.
                .Groupable()
        )

    </div>

    <style>
        #AjaxGrid {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

     <button class="btn btn-warning grid" type="button">Load Ajax KendoData</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('button.grid').click(function () {
        $("#AjaxGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        $("#AjaxGrid").css("display", "block");
    });
```

**Controller**

```
public class Default1Controller : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Default1/

        private Sales_DW db= new Sales_DW();

        public ActionResult KendoData()
        {
            return View();
        }

 public ActionResult KendoDataAjaxHandle([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            IQueryable<Customer> products = db.Customers;
            DataSourceResult result = products.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

on the click of the button, I am getting `Cannot read property dataSource of undefined` error on console.
Can someone please tell me as what I have done wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently doing the `Binding to local data` approach while building the grid.

If you want to [Bind with Remote Data](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/remote-data-binding) you need to set the `DataSource` of the grid.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.Customer>()
   //other details
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"))
     ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks Rajshekhar. Tried with this but still the same error.

Comment: @AakashThakur I made a small update here `.Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.Customer>()` check with this syntax

Comment: @AakashThakur if you have follwed the code I am sure the above mentioned error will not occur.. Can you update your question with the new changes you tried..

Comment: Edited Rajshekhar.

Answer (score 0):

Please have look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

set `visibility:hidden;`

I have't tested the code, its just a guess.